# Delphi: BeginDrag(False) and OnStartDrag

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, vcl

I call BeginDrag(False, 10) in OnMouseDown event.
Why OnStartDrag is called immediately?

I use OnStartDrag for some "heavy" initialization and I don't want it to be fired even on simple click.

Mouse behavior is ok (cursor is changed after mouse move), but event trigerring is to soon!

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug, at least I've encounter it using BDS 2006, don't know about newer Delphi versions though.

Answer (score 2):

> Why OnStartDrag is called immediately?

Because BeginDrag almost does nothing with Immediate and Threshold parameters (Except checking if Threshold is a negative number), and just passes them to DragInitControl in Controls unit.

DragInitControl procedure first checks if DragKind is dkDrag, if it is; then it calls DoStartDrag method which invokes OnStartDrag event. Later, at the end of DragInitControl code, DragInit is called which does the actual dragging job.

I don't know if this is by design, or a bug in implementing dragging in VCL. In Delphi documentation it [says](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/e/index.php/Controls.TControl.BeginDrag):

> If Immediate is false, the mouse
>   pointer does not change to the value
>   of the DragCursor property and
>   dragging does not begin until the user
>   moves the mouse pointer the number of
>   pixels specified by the Threshold
>   parameter.

Also for OnStartDrag the documentation [says](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/e/index.php/Controls.TControl.OnStartDrag):

> Occurs when the user begins to drag
>   the control or an object it contains
>   by left-clicking the control and
>   holding the mouse button down.

To me it means, if Immediate is False, and mouse is not moved, dragging is not started; therefore, OnStartDrag shouldn't be invoked.

Comment: Vcldeveloper, thanks for clear and detailed explanation, but in fact, i know that before i wrote here. Now i'm looking for a nice, clean solution. I tend to think it is an implementation bug. Are any chances to be fixed? Hey, Embarcadero? Mouse cursor is changed in right way, when dragging process starts. Can I intercept, hook, or maybe there is some WM_ to catch, when mouse cursor is changed or when real drag process starts? Thanks again.